# Passing Variables to a Modal

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

Is there anyway I can pass a javascript variable to a Modal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Try this.. while opening the modaldialog send the window as the parameter

```
showModalDialog(url,window,params);
```

and in the modal window

```
var parWin = window.dialogArguments;
```

now parWin contains your parent window object.

From here you can now access all data from your parent, be it variables or methods.

**Option 2:**

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
  var a = new Array;
  a[0]="first";
  a[1]="second";
  a[2]="third";
// -->
</SCRIPT>
```

And we pass the array a to the dialog box:

```
window.showModelessDialog('7b.html',a);
```

The callee 7b.html includes the following script:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
  a = dialogArguments;
  a[0] = "fourth";
// -->
</SCRIPT>
```

Some other reading on this:

http://www.webreference.com/js/column90/

http://www.webreference.com/js/column90/7.html

http://www.webreference.com/js/column90/8.html

Comment: One Correction: It is dialogArguments not dialogueArguments, but thanks for the great answer.

Comment: Sorry. I can't help it if the makers of JavaScript didn't spell things properly :)    Edited for clarity.